# intern 'Runner' reporter causes errors on Saucelabs, but not 'Console'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern, saucelabs

Using requirejs as the loader, tests run on Browserstack just fine, however when I try on SauceLabs I get the following error:

```
Fatal error during pre-execution stage 
Error: Load timeout for modules: intern/main!object, intern/chai!_unnormalized2, intern/chai!expect_unnormalized3, angularAMD, angularMocks...
requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout 
  at makeError <.../require.js:184:17> 
  at checkLoaded <.../require.js:860:23> at <.../require.js:892:25>
```

It seems switching to the 'Console' reporter instead of 'Runner' fixes the problem - why is this? 
I'm using intern-runner to start the tests, so should 'Runner' not be the most appropriate choice?

Comment: I don’t think your issue is actually related to the reporter in any way and you are simply experiencing Sauce Labs being its usual crummy self. (The warning in the docs about Sauce Labs exists for a reason.) In any case truncating the information from the test system in your post makes it difficult to provide any extra information so it would be good if you could provide the complete output of where the errors came from.

Comment: @CSnover is there something the runner reporter uses that the console doesn't that would be affected by bad output from SauceLabs? It reliably fails with runner and succeeds with console.

The output is actually different (I copied what their support provided)

Fatal error during pre-execution stage

Error: Load timeout for modules: intern/main!object, intern/chai!_unnormalized2, intern/chai!expect_unnormalized3, angularAMD, angularMocks...
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
at makeError <.../require.js:184:17>
at checkLoaded <.../require.js:860:23>
at <.../require.js:892:25>